# How to get the file size from HttpResponse

Tags: android, http, post, progressdialog

I need to show a progressbar while dowloading a file from a server, but I don't know how to grab the file size. I use a POST method like this

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        Inputstream toDown = null;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p1", p1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p2", p2));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p3", p3));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
            toDown = null;
        }

        else{
            toDown = response.getEntity().getContent();
        }
```

But I don't know what to do with this information to get the file size

Comment: sever may tell the "Content-Length" via response header

Comment: Yes but when I use response.getEntity().getContentLength() i get only -1.0

Comment: Then your server does not tell you the content length.

Answer (score 0):

Not all servers support the HEAD header. The following powershell code gets file size without downloading the file itself:

```
$param1 = 0
$param2 = 0
$param3 = "https://URI"

# Add the necessary .NET assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http

# Create the HttpClient object
$client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient
$client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Range = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Headers.RangeHeaderValue($param1, $param2)

$HttpMethod = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("get")
$HttpRequestMessage = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage($HttpMethod, $param3) 
$HttpResponseMessage = $client.SendAsync($HttpRequestMessage)
$HttpResponseMessage.wait();

$size = $HttpResponseMessage.result.content.headers.contentrange.length
echo $size
```

Tested on Powershell 5.1.17134.1, Win 10